# How to generate random value under the given distribution fast?

Tags: performance-tuning, random, distributions

Consider a distribution

```
distr[EN_, Enu_, mN_] = 
 Exp[-(Sqrt[EN^2 + mN^2]/Enu)]*Sqrt[(Sqrt[Enu^2-mN^2]/2)^2 - EN^2] Sqrt[
  EN^4 - (Enu/4)^4]
```

where mN is a free positive parameter, Enu>Sqrt[5]mN, and EN ranges within

```
ENmin[Enu_, mN_] = Max[mN, Enu/4];
ENmax[Enu_, mN_] = Sqrt[Enu^2-mN^2]/2;
```

`distr` is a probability distribution before the normalization, where `Enu,mN` are parameters, and EN is a variable.

Next, consider a dataset with Enu:

```
EnuVals = RandomReal[{0,60},10^6];
```

and a grid for mN:

```
mNvals=Table[x,{x,0.1,1.,0.1}];
```

My goal is to generate random values of EN (following the distribution `distr`) for the given values of Enu and mN. I.e. the desired final data would have rows

```
tabfinal={Enuvals[[i]],mNvals[[j]],ENrand[Enuvals[[i]],mNvals[[j]]]}
```

I do not have an idea how to quickly compute `ENrand` given the distribution `distr`. For particular values of Enu,mN, say Enuval,mNval, I would do the following:

```
ENvalsRandom = RandomReal[{ENmin[Enuval, mNval],ENmax[Enuval, mNval]}, 10000];
weights1 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{ENvalsRandom, _Real, 1}}, 
     Table[distr[ENvalsRandom[[i]],Enuval,mNval], {i, 1, 10000, 1}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@distr// 
  ReleaseHold;
weights = weights1[ENvalsRandom];
weightedData = WeightedData[tabRPPS, weights];
edist = EmpiricalDistribution[weightedData];
ENvalRandomTrue = RandomVariate[edist, 1]
```

But this way is really slow since it requires building the empirical distribution `Length[mNvals]*Length[EnuVals]` times.

Could you please suggest how to optimize it?

Comment: I can't understand what random variable is of interest.  And what is `distr`?  Is that a probability density function?  cumulative probability density function?  Something else?  Are all of the arguments for `distr` parameters?  Is one of those the random variable of interest?

Comment: @JimB : Thanks! I have updated the question. `distr` is a probability distribution before the normalization, where `Enu,mN` are parameters, and EN is a variable.

Comment: The random selection of `Enu` values will need to be changed from `RandomReal[{0, 60},10^6]` to `RandomReal[{Sqrt[5] mN, 60},10^6]` because if $0<mN\leq 1$, then $Enu>\sqrt{5}mN$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you'll have to give up on "fast" for your un-normalized density function, as you'll need to normalize it numerically with specific values for `mN` and `Enu` and use the "invert the cdf" approach where both the "invert" and "cdf" parts both need to be found numerically.  If there was a closed-form for the cdf (which seems doubtful), that would help.

Here is a brute-force approach when specifying values for `mN` and `Enu`:

```
(* Set parameters *)
mN = 1;
Enu = 5;

(* Constant of integration *)
const = NIntegrate[Exp[-(Sqrt[en^2 + mN^2]/Enu)]*
  Sqrt[(Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2)^2 - en^2] Sqrt[en^4 - (Enu/4)^4], 
  {en, Max[mN, Enu/4], Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2}]
(* 3.03052 *)

(* cdf of random variable EN *)
cdf[EN_] := Module[{}, 
  If[EN < Max[mN, Enu/4], 0, 
   If[EN > Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2, 1, 
    NIntegrate[Exp[-(Sqrt[en^2 + mN^2]/Enu)]*
      Sqrt[(Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2)^2 - en^2] Sqrt[en^4 - (Enu/4)^4]/const,
    {en, Max[mN, Enu/4], EN}] ]]]

(* The cdf has a uniform(0,1) so we take a random sample from a uniform distribution
  and then solve for the corresponding EN *)
(* Take n random samples *)
SeedRandom[12345];
n = 1000;
(* Starting value for EN *)
en0 = (Max[mN, Enu/4] + Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2)/2;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sample = Table[EN /. FindRoot[cdf[EN] == RandomReal[{0, 1}], {{EN, en0}}], {i, n}];
 ]
(* {20.7947, Null} *)

(* Show results *)
Show [Histogram[sample, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> {{1, 2.5}, Automatic}],
  Plot[Exp[-(Sqrt[en^2 + mN^2]/Enu)]*
    Sqrt[(Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2)^2 - en^2] Sqrt[en^4 - (Enu/4)^4]/const, 
  {en, Max[mN, Enu/4], Sqrt[Enu^2 - mN^2]/2}]]
```

[image: Histogram and true density]